# Laravel: Display data in drop-down from database

Tags: laravel

Hello guys I have a problem in my code ***Undefined variable: reports_categories***. I am trying to make a drop down list with the name of categories which they are in my database. Here is what i have done:

```
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'reports.create','role' => 'form', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')) !!}
                        {{csrf_field()}} 
                        {{method_field('PUT')}}

                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-2 pull-right"style="margin-top: 50px">
                            <div class="select-style input-round med-input shop-shorting-full">
                                <select name="category_id" id="" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="">Select Category</option>
                                    @foreach($reports_categories as $category)
                                        <option
                                             value="{{$category->id}}"
                                             @if($category->id === $reports->category_id)
                                                selected
                                             @endif
                                             >
                                             {{$category->name}}
                                        </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                {!! Form::close() !!}
```

And here is my ReportsController:

```
   public function index(){
   //Show all created reports
   $reports = Reports::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);
   return view('reports.index', ['reports'=>compact('reports')])->with(['reports', $reports]);
    }  
                                                                                                                                         
    public function create()
    {
        $reports = 'reports';
        return view('reports.create',['reports'=>$reports]);
    } 
                                                                                                                                         
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //Validate fields
        $this->validate($request, [
            'title' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'address' => 'required'
        ]);

        //Create Report
        $reports = new Reports;
        $reports->title = $request->input('title');
        $reports->description = $request->input('description');
        $reports->address = $request->input('address');
        $reports->reports_categories_id = auth()-            
                >reports_categories()->id;
        $reports->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $reports->save();

        return redirect('/reports')->with('success', 'ReportCreated');
    }
                                                                                                                                       
    public function show($id)
    {
        $reports = Reports::find($id);
        $reports_categories = DB::table('reports_categories')->where('reports_categories_id', $id)->get();
        return view('reports.show', ['report'=>$reports, 'reports_categories'=>$reports_categories]);   
    }
```

Please if you know what is the problem or you have any suggestion let me know.
If you need more details tell me and I will provide more information.

Comment: Please correct    return view('reports.show', ['report'=>$reports, 'reports_categories'=>$categories]); it should be 'reports_categories'=>$reports_categories

Comment: What is your blade name file ?

Comment: The blade name is create.blade.php

Comment: @mightyteja i fixed that but still

Answer (score 0):

If this is related to your 'show' function then you're passing a variable called $categories instead of $reports_categories which you used for the DB query here:

```
 public function show($id)
{
    $reports = Reports::find($id);
    $reports_categories = DB::table('reports_categories')->where('reports_categories_id', $id)->get();
    return view('reports.show', ['report'=>$reports, 'reports_categories'=>$categories]);   
}
```

Change the variable you're returning to the view to $reports_categories.

If that form is on your 'create' function view then you're not passing it at all to that page. If you're using a create form that requires it, maybe that's the problem? Hard to know without knowing which page that form is on.

Comment: Yea I changed $categories to $reports_categories but i still get the same error. Could you explain again the second part of your response?